# Q: how to describe these results by a descendants tree in gap

Tags: lattice-orders, gap, computer-algebra-systems, p-groups, computational-algebra

I wrote an implement to find the "fullyInvariantGroups" in GAP and the results appeared as below:

```
FullyInvariantGroups := function( p, r, l )  
    local G, grps, i, j, P, M, N, A, B, C, D, c, b, m, n, aa, bb, a, w, v;

    # set up
    G := ElementaryAbelianGroup(p^r);
    grps := [[[false, G]]];

    # loop
    for i in [1..l-1] do
        Print("starting level ",i," with ", Length(grps[i])," groups \n");
        grps[i+1] := [];
        for j in [1..Length(grps[i])] do
            G := grps[i][j][2];
            P := PCoverPGroup(G);
            M := P!.mult; m := Length(Pcgs(M));
            N := P!.nucl; n := Length(Pcgs(N));
            if n > 0 then 
                Print(" Level ",i," group ",j,"\n");
                A := GetAutAction(P);
                B := GModuleByMats( A, GF(p));
                w := SMTX.CollectedFactors(B);
                v := List(w, x -> x[2]);
                if ForAny(v, x -> x <> 1) then Error("hier"); fi;
                w := List(w, x -> x[1].dimension);
                C := SMTX.BasesSubmodules(B);
                D := Filtered(C, x -> IsAllowable(M,N,x));
                for c in D do
                    if i < l-1 then 
                        b := SubgroupByBasis(M, c);
                        Add(grps[i+1], [j, P/b]); 
                    else
                        Add(grps[i+1], [j, 1]);
                    fi;
                od;
            fi;
            grps[i][j][2] := 1;
        od;
    od;
    return grps;
    return TwigCanoForm(grps);
end;
```

> gap> FullyInvariantGroups(7,2,5);
>   starting level 1 with 1 groups
>    Level 1 group 1
>   starting level 2 with 3 groups
>    Level 2 group 1
>    Level 2 group 2
>    Level 2 group 3
>   starting level 3 with 9 groups
>    Level 3 group 1
>    Level 3 group 2
>    Level 3 group 3
>    Level 3 group 4
>    Level 3 group 5
>    Level 3 group 6
>    Level 3 group 8
>    Level 3 group 9
>   starting level 4 with 28 groups
>    Level 4 group 1
>    Level 4 group 2
>    Level 4 group 3
>    Level 4 group 4
>    Level 4 group 5
>    Level 4 group 6
>    Level 4 group 7
>    Level 4 group 8
>    Level 4 group 9
>    Level 4 group 10
>    Level 4 group 11
>    Level 4 group 12
>    Level 4 group 13
>    Level 4 group 16
>    Level 4 group 17
>    Level 4 group 18
>    Level 4 group 19
>    Level 4 group 20
>    Level 4 group 22
>    Level 4 group 23
>    Level 4 group 25
>    Level 4 group 26
>    Level 4 group 27
>    Level 4 group 28
>   [ [ [ false, 1 ] ], [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ], 
>     [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ] ], 
>     [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], 
>         [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], 
>         [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 8, 1 ], [ 9, 1 ] ], 
>     [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], 
>         [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], 
>         [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], 
>         [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], 
>         [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], 
>         [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], 
>         [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], 
>         [ 2, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], 
>         [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], 
>         [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 4, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], 
>         [ 5, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], 
>         [ 6, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 7, 1 ], [ 8, 1 ], [ 9, 1 ], [ 9, 1 ], 
>         [ 9, 1 ], [ 10, 1 ], [ 10, 1 ], [ 10, 1 ], [ 11, 1 ], [ 12, 1 ], [ 12, 1 ], [ 12, 1 ], [ 13, 1 ], [ 16, 1 ], 
>         [ 16, 1 ], [ 16, 1 ], [ 16, 1 ], [ 16, 1 ], [ 16, 1 ], [ 16, 1 ], [ 17, 1 ], [ 17, 1 ], [ 17, 1 ], [ 18, 1 ], 
>         [ 19, 1 ], [ 19, 1 ], [ 19, 1 ], [ 19, 1 ], [ 19, 1 ], [ 19, 1 ], [ 19, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], 
>         [ 22, 1 ], [ 22, 1 ], [ 22, 1 ], [ 23, 1 ], [ 25, 1 ], [ 25, 1 ], [ 25, 1 ], [ 26, 1 ], [ 27, 1 ], [ 28, 1 ], 
>         [ 28, 1 ], [ 28, 1 ] ] ]

Is there any way in GAP to made up tree from this outcome to be easy for reading and analyzing?? 
 im sorry but i'm a newbie in GAP.

Comment: Could this be achieved with GAP records? Please see https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap29.html to decide.

Comment: Also, it may be worth to ask the authors of the GAP "datastructures" package: https://github.com/gap-packages/datastructures/issues

Comment: However, a list of lists may also work well, if you store some further details. What's the meaning of pairs of integers? Are these `GroupId`s? Also, which kind of analysis of the output you have in mind?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov thank you so much for your comment. I have edited my question i think its become clear. this is a description to the groups and i want to build up a trees from this outcome.

Comment: The pairs of integers as example  [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ], mean that the group number 1 have 3 subgroups and its represent the second level from the tree of descendants after the first level which represent by the root (main group, parent) .. ect.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov can i represent the outcomes as a matrix ??

Comment: For a graph, surely you can.  But for a descendants tree, adjacency matrix will be very sparse, so that will be very inefficient. [Adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) could be a better representation.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I feel frustrated about this, because I am a beginner in this field and I face difficulties in programming and graphics.

Comment: That's fine, I never had time to write anything more detailed than a quick-fire comment. Perhaps someone will be wiling to post a proper answer. A good answer could have a generic code for keeping objects and tracing their descendants, usable with a separate function that takes one object and computes its immediate descendants.

Comment: Are the two new answers helpful, or you had in mind something different? Could you please let us know!

Answer (score 2):

You may use dot language to create a tree, and then [graphviz](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/) to produce an image (or any JavaScript library that reads dot language, as d3js, viz.js ...). You may find some examples under the [dot chapter](https://gap-packages.github.io/numericalsgps/doc/chap14.html#X7B8D661F79E957A6) of [numericalsgps](https://gap-packages.github.io/numericalsgps/). Also you can create a binary relation (parent,child) and then use `DotBinaryRelation` in that package.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GAP on a Mac, it wouldn't be so difficult to write code to display a tree in a graphic window with [Gap.app](https://cocoagap.sourceforge.io/).  (Or you can use xgap on Linux, but the interface is clunky enough to be distracting.)  Sample code which displays the partition lattice is on my [website](https://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~russ.woodroofe/programming.html), and might give you a reasonable start.  Indeed, with a little more work you could set up so that you can right-click on a node to get a more detail description!

UPDATE: Easily viewing trees would be useful for me, also, so I went ahead and wrote a routine that will display a rooted tree.  It's posted on my webpage as "rooted-tree.g".

UPDATE2: added screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thank you so much. Iam using GAP on linux  and i tried to install xgap but its dose not gone well

Comment: How is your GAP installed?  Did you build it yourself, or are you installing it as a Debian package or similar?  If you're trying to build it yourself, you'll need a bunch of X Windows development packages to be installed for the header files.  And you'll need the Xaw libs.